# Intellisense doesn't find uint8_t and uint16_t in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the C/C++ plugin for VSCode and the new intellisense engine (`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"`).
I use C99 and its width-specific types like `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`. The problem I have is that VSCode marks every use of `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` as red since it doesn't seem to find the declarations for them, while other types like `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` are just fine.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have tried using the default settings for finding include files as well as limiting to clang includes, but neither work. How can this be solved?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, GCC 7.2.0, latest VSCode, and I having exact same problem. Can't solve this still.

Comment: Once I checked the system include paths of gcc using gcc -E -Wp,-v -xc /dev/null and used that then it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I updated with the correct include (and browse) directories it worked.
I used the command

```
gcc -E -Wp,-v -xc /dev/null
```

to get that info.